# TypeError: driver.bswitchTo() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I installed 'React-google-login' to react project. And I am writing an autotest that should bypass this module.

```
try {
    await driver.get("http://localhost:3000/");
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div/button`)), 10000).click();

    await driver.getAllWindowHandles().then( function(handles){
       driver.bswitchTo().window(handles[1]).then(function(){
          driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('identifierId')),10000).sendKeys('test@gmail.com', Key.ENTER)
          });
    });
    await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath(`//*[@id="root"]/div/h2[2]/span`)), 10000).click();

    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
```

Switching between windows does not always occur and produces such an error:

```
TypeError: driver.bswitchTo is not a function
```

What can I do?

Comment: @RapperAB, thnx, your comment helped solve the problem

Comment: Anytime my friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that driver.switchTo() must be there instead of bswitchTo(). Please mark this answer as accepted if it has helped you in any way :)